# HTML5 Video custom controller in full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, html5-video

HTML5 Video full screen custom controller not appearing properly in Mozilla Firefox.

[image]

DEMO http://athimannil.com/player/

```
:-webkit-full-screen #skinn{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
:-moz-full-screen #skinn{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
:-ms-fullscreen #skinn{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
:fullscreen #skinn{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: worked for me: `FF 29.0.1` on MacBook Pro

Comment: @aldanux is the width 100% in your browser ?

Comment: Yes the only issue is that your `controller` don't disappear

Comment: @aldanux Yes, it doesn't work same like other browser :(

Comment: I tested now on iMac 26" in FF 29.0.1 - The same: width: 100% is perfect but controller don't disappear

Answer (score 0):

You make kuttuPlayer, which is #player1, your fullscreen element. #skinn is not a child element of your fullscreen element. Therefore the CSS selectors don't match. Don't forget that you may only have a part of your DOM in your fullscreen view.

Try something like:

```
#skinn:-moz-full-screen-ancestor {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And the differences between gecko and webkit are documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Presentation_differences